# Image Map Not Working In IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dictionary, imagemap

I have an image map on my site, and it works in everything except IE.

This is the code:

```
    <div id="content">
    <div style="text-align:center; width:302px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <img id="alexpeteNav" src="nav.jpg" usemap="Aalexpetenav" border="0" width="302" height="274" alt="" />
    <map id="BalexpeteNav" name="AalexpeteNav">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,297,72" href="http://doubleohnine.com/" alt="009" title="009" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,68,297,140" href="about.html" alt="About alexpete" title="About alexpete" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,139,297,211" href="https://plus.google.com/104897364451129767176" alt="Google+" title="Google+" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,209,297,269" href="http://www.facebook.com/alexpete" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" />
    </map>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

Any suggestions? Reasons?

The site is online at www.alexpete.com.

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`usemap` expects a valid [hash-name reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.hash-name) to an image map, i.e. `#` before the map name.

I guess the other browsers are more lenient in that regard.

Comment: @pekka  Can you please look into my question and help me http://stackoverflow.com/q/24078704/2118383